# Why Skype can use HTTP proxy for real-time audio communication?

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, udp, skype

I used to think Skype sends and receives UDP data packets for real-time audio communication so it cannot use HTTP proxy as HTTP is based on TCP, as what people usually think. But in the support site of Skype, there is an article about HTTP proxy saying that'll affect how Skype makes the communication.

Answer (score 1):

Skype uses different protocols based on the capabilities of the network. If it is behind a firewall and can not call out directly with UDP it will try to detect a HTTP proxy and use it to tunnel the traffic using a proxy CONNECT request. This means it will use TCP in this case. While this might degrade the quality of the connection because latency is often better with UDP (at the cost of data loss), this is often better than no connection at all.